# Angular-slick при удалении элемента из ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, slider, slick.js

Есть хорошо работающий слайдер:

```
<slick dots=true slides-to-show="10" slides-to-scroll="9" arrows="false" ng-if="allProducts.length"> 
                <div ng-repeat="item in allProducts">
                <small>{{item.Name}}</small>
                </div>
            </slick>
```

Есть также кнопка которая удаляет из этого слайдера один элемент `item`. После удаления, слайдер перестаёт работать и все элементы как бы "выпадают" из слайдера и находятся на странице как будто это обычные блоки `div`
Как можно решить данную проблему? Чтобы элемент удался из слайдера, но слайдер оставался рабоатать?

**UPD**

[На этой странице](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) показано как можно удалить элемент встроенными функциями, но что-то я не разобрался как его применить,не могу понять откуда берется `slideIndex`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

добавьте `init-onload=true data="allProducts.length"`  к `slick` тегу.

чтобы получилось что-то вроде:

```
<slick slides-to-show=3 slides-to-scroll=3 init-onload=true data="awesomeThings" class="slider multiple-items">
      <div ng-repeat="thing in awesomeThings"><h3>{{ thing }}</h3></div>
    </slick>
```

Comment: и как это поможет удалению элемента?

Comment: это мне не помогло.

Comment: @Grundy вотчер следит за изменениями в data и реинициализирует компонент https://github.com/vasyabigi/angular-slick/blob/master/dist/slick.js#L147

Comment: @a.tarasevich вы уверены, чтобы при удалении элемента allProducts изменился?

Comment: @a.tarasevich init-onload=true еще добавьте.

Comment: @tcpack4, забавно, интересно почему они watchCollection Не стали тут использовать. удаление наверняка было через какой-нибудь splice, поэтому изменений быть не должно замечено

Comment: да, спасибо, помогло! Только нужно не allProducts, a allProducts.length

Comment: @Grundy правильное замечание)

Comment: @tcpack4 как оказалось не совсем корректно работает. А точнее слайдер после удаления остаётся слайдером (благодаря вашему ответу), но элемент теперь не удаляется из слайдера..

Comment: по идее вы все сделали правильно. так что скорее баг в компоненте)